# Applying AllowLimitedAccess option to a specific Sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to allow limited, browser only access to a specific Sharepoint site. I am following the document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/control-access-from-unmanaged-devices#block-or-limit-access-to-a-specific-sharepoint-site-or-onedrive and want to do it using PowerShell. While the commands seems to work I don't see anything happening to the site. I can continue to access the site with full access and download files.
The instructions say *Manually create a policy in the Azure AD admin center by following the steps in Use app-enforced restrictions.*. I believe we can name the policy as per our wish. But how does it link with the below PowerShell command.

`Set-SPOSite -Identity https://<SharePoint online URL>/sites/<name of site or OneDrive account> -ConditionalAccessPolicy AllowLimitedAccess`

Is `AllowLimitedAccess` a built-in policy? If yes then why do we have to create another policy? Has anyone got this working? Am I missing something?

Comment: I think Manually created policy is only required if you want to set site-level setting using "sensitivity label". Try command in this format directly `Set-SPOSite -Identity https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/mySite -ConditionalAccessPolicy AllowLimitedAccess` and wait up to 24 hours for the policy to take effect. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have left it for 48 hours and still nothing is changed. I have even tried the `BlockAccess` option and still no luck.